# What is the best way to solve the issue of encountering division by zero when normalizing an image?

Tags: image, normalization

What is the best way to solve the issue of encountering division by zero when normalizing an image?

Currently, what I am doing now is to replace the nan values with zero. Is there a proper way to do this? Will replacing by zero affect the result of normalization?

Comment: What is your normal form and why are you using it in what context? If you are encountering division by zero then your normalization operation is either inappropriate or you have programmed it erroneously.

Comment: @philipxy I am normalizing an image and I am using mean std normalization. It is possible that an image has a standard deviation of zero? No?

Comment: A z-score has standared deviation 1. If you claim that sigma is 0 then you do not have a normal distribution & have violated applicability assumptions. Eg [What is the z score when the standard deviation is 0 ?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080407082934AAFbhYX) or [Why Z-Scores Have Mean 0, Standard Deviation 1](http://www.madmath.com/2013/07/why-z-scores-have-mean-0-standard.html). Consider posting this to [stats.se].

Comment: No procedure needs to divide by zero it because it's undefined. So somewhere in your solution development you have made an error. Also "normalizing an image" & "using" are just not detailed enough. Please give an outline of your situation and details of your problem, reasoning, math, language & code, also what references you are to use.